# Javascript create bookmark from text link href when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text link that has a dynamic href.

```
<a href="/search?s=0&amp;pg=1&amp;pp=100&amp;z=True&amp;de=True" id="BookmarkLink" class="bookmarkLink" target="_blank" title="Copy and share search result">bookmark</a>
```

The URL in the href updates with the search parameters, each time a search is refined.

```
http://website.com./search?s=0&pg=1&pp=100&z=True&de=True
```

I currently have a script that copies the text link href to the users clipboard.

However I want a cross browser script that will allow the link to create a new bookmark / bookmarklet.

Is this possible? I've read that Chrome and Safari no longer support such functions or scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this example?

[Cross-browser bookmark button with demo](https://www.thewebflash.com/how-to-add-a-cross-browser-add-to-favorites-bookmark-button-to-your-website/)

Comment: I did see that, however it calls up an alert in Chrome and Safari because the function doesn't work in WebKit and Blink browsers.